# How to declare NSString* C style array as global variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my main iOS project I have the following situation: 
In file1.m I have:

```
NSString* s[] = {@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"};
```

In file2.m I have:

```
extern NSString** s;
```

In the same file2.m the method below fails with "unrecognized selector 'length' sent to instance':

```
- (void) someMethod {
    int len = [s[0] length];
}
```

If I create a new demo project and I copy the code above everything works as expected.
What could be the problem with my main project? I'm stuck here for 2 days trying to find the problem.
The same problem appears with int arrays with the difference that I receive bad access exception when I try to access the elements in the array, although the XCode debugger shows the array content just fine.

Comment: Why? Why can you not use NSArray?

Comment: When you run in the debugger what is s[0]?

Comment: For the s array the debugger displays a list of memory addresses but no string content as if the values in the array are not properly initialized.

Comment: @duDE No, that's a very bad thing to do, because the project wouldn't link.

Comment: @iPDFdev It looks like the array elements have been released somehow.

Comment: I'm a little bewildered why you wouldn't just use an NSArray ...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't think they are released. The literals shouldn't be released anyway. He's getting `unrecognized selector` that means there is a valid object inside. I think he is overwriting the data somewhere.

Comment: @Sulthan There may be another object in the place where `NSString`s were originally, before deallocation. This is very suspicious.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - your first suggestion was right, the array name was already used somewhere. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it. The actual array name is 'pdfFontName'. The name is not used anywhere in my project but I assume it is used in some libraries by Apple and this caused the problem. If I renamed it 'pdfFontName1' it worked without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that the global array name declared with `extern` matches the name of the array that you reference in the call of `length` (i.e. the `s` in `extern NSString** s;` and `[s[0] length]` is the same name), and that there is no other variable named `s` in the scope of the call of `length` that would "shadow" the global. Since the code works fine in a smaller project, naming collision is the most likely possibility.

Comment: Really, though, use an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
extern NSString** s;
```

you just declare a pointer to the pointer of an NSString object, the correct declaration should be:

```
extern NSString *s[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas what could be happening there.

1. You are overwriting the array somewhere. It's always helpful to declare constant C arrays with `const`
2. Variable name collision
   You have two globals with the same name but different objects. Using
   globals with names like `s` can lead to collisions easily. Make sure
   to use prefixes for globals, exactly in the same way as you are
   doing for classes, enums, etc.